# double table html on ajax pagination request - wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Dear Wordpress Developer,

Hello, I want to ask something.

Actually, the code is running. But I don't understand why when click ajax pagination, there is 0 value appear. And when I check on developer tools, the ajax pagination resulting 2 div id="data" and that make 0 value appear. Here is the image:
[image]

I don't know where the code gone wrong. Please take a look at my code:

display-cpt.php

```
class displayCPT{

    static function displayAllUniversity(){
        global $wpdb;

        $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
        $limit = 3;
        $limit_start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
        $no = $limit_start + 1;

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
        $allUniversity = new WP_QUERY(array(
            'post_type' => 'university',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => $limit,
            'offset' => $limit_start
        ));

        $total_records = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name WHERE post_type = 'university' AND post_status = 'publish'", array() ));

        if($allUniversity->have_posts()){
            ?>
            <div id="data">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 50%">
                                <h2><strong>Nama Universitas</strong></h2>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <h2><strong>Lokasi Universitas</strong></h2>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <h2><strong>Jurusan Tersedia</strong></h2>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <h2><strong>Beasiswa Tersedia</strong></h2>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php
                    while($allUniversity->have_posts()){
                        $allUniversity->the_post();
                        ?>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td data-label="Nama Universitas">
                                    <?php 
                                        $university_logo = get_field('university_logo');
                                        $size = 'medium';
                                        if( ! empty ( $university_logo ) ) {
                                            echo wp_get_attachment_image($university_logo, $size, "", array( "class" => "img-responsive" ));
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <p style="font-size: x-large;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></p>
                                    <details>
                                        <summary>lihat detail &raquo;</summary>
                                        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 15); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Baca Selengkapnya &raquo;</a></p>
                                    </details>
                                </td>
                                <td data-label="Lokasi Universitas">
                                    <p><?php $university_locations = the_field('university_location'); ?></p>
                                </td>
                                <td data-label="Jurusan Tersedia">
                                    <p><?php $university_majors = the_field('university_major'); ?></p>
                                </td>
                                <td data-label="Beasiswa Tersedia">
                                    <?php 
                                    
                                    $university_scholarships = get_field('university_scholarship');
                                    
                                    if(count((array)$university_scholarships) > 0):
                                    ?>
                                        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo count($university_scholarships); ?> Beasiswa</a></p>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">0 Beasiswa</a></p>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                                                
                        </tbody>
                        <?php 
                    }
                    ?>
                </table>

                <p>Total baris : <?php echo $total_records; ?></p>

                <nav class="mb-5">
                    <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">

                    <?php 
                        $jumlah_page = ceil($total_records / $limit);
                        $jumlah_number = 1; //jumlah halaman ke kanan dan kiri dari halaman yang aktif
                        $start_number = ($page > $jumlah_number)? $page - $jumlah_number : 1;
                        $end_number = ($page < ($jumlah_page - $jumlah_number))? $page + $jumlah_number : $jumlah_page;
                        if($page == 1){
                            echo '<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">First</a></li>';
                            echo '<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>';
                        } else {
                        $link_prev = ($page > 1)? $page - 1 : 1;
                            echo '<li class="page-item halaman" id="1"><a class="page-link">First</a></li>';
                            echo '<li class="page-item halaman" id="'.$link_prev.'"><a class="page-link"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>';
                        }
                        for($i = $start_number; $i <= $end_number; $i++){
                            $link_active = ($page == $i)? ' active' : '';
                            echo '<li class="page-item halaman '.$link_active.'" id="'.$i.'"><a class="page-link">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                        }
                        if($page == $jumlah_page){
                            echo '<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a></li>';
                            echo '<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">Last</a></li>';
                        } else {
                        $link_next = ($page < $jumlah_page)? $page + 1 : $jumlah_page;
                            echo '<li class="page-item halaman" id="'.$link_next.'"><a class="page-link"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a></li>';
                            echo '<li class="page-item halaman" id="'.$jumlah_page.'"><a class="page-link">Last</a></li>';
                        }

                        ?>

                    </ul>


                </nav>
            </div>
            <?php

            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is ajax-pagination.js

```
import $ from "jquery";

class ajaxPagination{
    constructor(){
        this.events();
    }

    events(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click', '.halaman', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var page = $(this).attr("id");
                $.ajax({
                    url: pluginData.ajax_url,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data:{
                      'action': 'displayAllUniversity',
                      'page': page
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#data').html(response);
                       
                    }
                  
               })
            });

        });
    }


}

export default ajaxPagination;
```

and then this is inside posts-type.php

```
class postsType{

    function __construct(){
        add_action( 'init', array('registerCPT', 'register_menu_page'));
        
        add_shortcode('displayAllUniversity', array('displayCPT', 'displayAllUniversity'));

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_displayAllUniversity', array('displayCPT','displayAllUniversity') );

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_displayAllUniversity', array('displayCPT','displayAllUniversity')); 


    }

}

$PostsType = new postsType;
```

and this is inside functions.php

```
function plugin_assets(){
    wp_enqueue_script("enqueue_plugin_scripts", POSTS_TYPE_URL . 'build/index.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_style("enqueue_plugin_style", POSTS_TYPE_URL . 'build/style-index.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('dashicons');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'boostrap', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');

    wp_localize_script('enqueue_plugin_scripts', 'pluginData', array(
        'ajax_url' =>  admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" )
    ));

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'plugin_assets');
```

this is inside register-cpt.php

```
static function register_menu_page(){
        if(is_plugin_active('posts-type/posts-type.php')){
            register_post_type('university', array(
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
                'has_archieve' => true,
                'public' => true,
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => 'University',
                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New University',
                    'edit_item' => 'Edit University',
                    'all_item' => 'All University',
                    'singular_name' => 'University'
                ),
                'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-building'
            ));
        }

    }
```

any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Best Regards,

Hendra

UPDATED CODE

I'm deleted  and give it to table. The double table already fixed, but still get "0" below. And then I follow @vel directions to use `$('.entry-content').empty().html(response);` on my ajax success.

Here is the code:

```
 static function displayAllUniversity(){
        global $wpdb;

        $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
        $limit = 3;
        $limit_start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
        $no = $limit_start + 1;

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
        $allUniversity = new WP_QUERY(array(
            'post_type' => 'university',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => $limit,
            'offset' => $limit_start
        ));

        $total_records = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name WHERE post_type = 'university' AND post_status = 'publish'", array() ));

        if($allUniversity->have_posts()){
            ?>
                <table class="table" id="data">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 50%">
                                <h2><strong>Nama Universitas</strong></h2>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <h2><strong>Lokasi Universitas</strong></h2>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <h2><strong>Jurusan Tersedia</strong></h2>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <h2><strong>Beasiswa Tersedia</strong></h2>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php
                    while($allUniversity->have_posts()){
                        $allUniversity->the_post();
                        ?>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td data-label="Nama Universitas">
                                    <?php 
                                        $university_logo = get_field('university_logo');
                                        $size = 'medium';
                                        if( ! empty ( $university_logo ) ) {
                                            echo wp_get_attachment_image($university_logo, $size, "", array( "class" => "img-responsive" ));
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <p style="font-size: x-large;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></p>
                                    <details>
                                        <summary>lihat detail &raquo;</summary>
                                        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 15); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Baca Selengkapnya &raquo;</a></p>
                                    </details>
                                </td>
                                <td data-label="Lokasi Universitas">
                                    <p><?php $university_locations = the_field('university_location'); ?></p>
                                </td>
                                <td data-label="Jurusan Tersedia">
                                    <p><?php $university_majors = the_field('university_major'); ?></p>
                                </td>
                                <td data-label="Beasiswa Tersedia">
                                    <?php 
                                    
                                    $university_scholarships = get_field('university_scholarship');
                                    
                                    if(count((array)$university_scholarships) > 0):
                                    ?>
                                        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo count($university_scholarships); ?> Beasiswa</a></p>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">0 Beasiswa</a></p>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                                                
                        </tbody>
                        <?php 
                    }
                    ?>
                </table>

                <p>Total baris : <?php echo $total_records; ?></p>

                <nav class="mb-5">
                    <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">

                    <?php 
                        $jumlah_page = ceil($total_records / $limit);
                        $jumlah_number = 1; //jumlah halaman ke kanan dan kiri dari halaman yang aktif
                        $start_number = ($page > $jumlah_number)? $page - $jumlah_number : 1;
                        $end_number = ($page < ($jumlah_page - $jumlah_number))? $page + $jumlah_number : $jumlah_page;
                        if($page == 1){
                            echo '<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">First</a></li>';
                            echo '<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>';
                        } else {
                        $link_prev = ($page > 1)? $page - 1 : 1;
                            echo '<li class="page-item halaman" id="1"><a class="page-link">First</a></li>';
                            echo '<li class="page-item halaman" id="'.$link_prev.'"><a class="page-link"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>';
                        }
                        for($i = $start_number; $i <= $end_number; $i++){
                            $link_active = ($page == $i)? ' active' : '';
                            echo '<li class="page-item halaman '.$link_active.'" id="'.$i.'"><a class="page-link">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                        }
                        if($page == $jumlah_page){
                            echo '<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a></li>';
                            echo '<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">Last</a></li>';
                        } else {
                        $link_next = ($page < $jumlah_page)? $page + 1 : $jumlah_page;
                            echo '<li class="page-item halaman" id="'.$link_next.'"><a class="page-link"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a></li>';
                            echo '<li class="page-item halaman" id="'.$jumlah_page.'"><a class="page-link">Last</a></li>';
                        }

                        ?>

                    </ul>


                </nav>
  
            <?php

            wp_reset_postdata();
            
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: `$('#data').empty().html(response);` you missed `empty()` before append

Comment: Hello @Vel, Thank you for answering. I'm already do what you told me to do, but still not fixed.

Comment: do not send ` <div id="data">` this div in ajax response.

Comment: Hello @Vel, I'm tried to understand what you mean. But, I'm still don't understand. Can you please give me link to learn? Thank You

Comment: remove this `div` from ajax response ` <div id="data">`

Comment: if I remove ```<div id="data">``` then where ```var page = $(this).attr("id");``` target the html from? @Vel

Comment: that ```<div id="data">``` is like overwriting all over the table to selected page.  So, that cannot be deleted.

Comment: you are calling pagination on button click event. I dont know how you are loading on page load time.

Comment: I'm already edited my full code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code. Just removed this div only `<div id="data">`. Not whole html.**

```
static function displayAllUniversity(){
    global $wpdb;

    $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $limit = 3;
    $limit_start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    $no = $limit_start + 1;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
    $allUniversity = new WP_QUERY(array(
        'post_type' => 'university',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => $limit,
        'offset' => $limit_start
    ));

    $total_records = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name WHERE post_type = 'university' AND post_status = 'publish'", array() ));

    if($allUniversity->have_posts()){
        ?>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 50%;">
                            <h2><strong>Nama Universitas</strong></h2>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h2><strong>Lokasi Universitas</strong></h2>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h2><strong>Jurusan Tersedia</strong></h2>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h2><strong>Beasiswa Tersedia</strong></h2>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
                while($allUniversity->have_posts()){
                    $allUniversity->the_post();
                    ?>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-label="Nama Universitas">
                            <?php 
                                $university_logo = get_field('university_logo');
                                $size = 'medium';
                                if( ! empty ( $university_logo ) ) {
                                    echo wp_get_attachment_image($university_logo, $size, "", array( "class" => "img-responsive" ));
                                }
                            ?>
                            <p style="font-size: x-large"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                            <details>
                                <summary>lihat detail &raquo;</summary>
                                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 15); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Baca Selengkapnya &raquo;</a></p>
                            </details>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Lokasi Universitas">
                            <p><?php $university_locations = the_field('university_location'); ?></p>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Jurusan Tersedia">
                            <p><?php $university_majors = the_field('university_major'); ?></p>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Beasiswa Tersedia">
                            <?php 
                            
                            $university_scholarships = get_field('university_scholarship');
                            
                            if(count((array)$university_scholarships) > 0):
                            ?>
                                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo count($university_scholarships); ?> Beasiswa</a></p>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">0 Beasiswa</a></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                                           
                </tbody>
                    <?php 
                }
                ?>
            </table>

            <p>Total baris : <?php echo $total_records; ?></p>

            <nav class="mb-5">
                <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">

                <?php 
                    $jumlah_page = ceil($total_records / $limit);
                    $jumlah_number = 1; //jumlah halaman ke kanan dan kiri dari halaman yang aktif
                    $start_number = ($page > $jumlah_number)? $page - $jumlah_number : 1;
                    $end_number = ($page < ($jumlah_page - $jumlah_number))? $page + $jumlah_number : $jumlah_page;
                    if($page == 1){
                        echo '<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">First</a></li>';
                        echo '<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>';
                    } else {
                    $link_prev = ($page > 1)? $page - 1 : 1;
                        echo '<li class="page-item halaman" id="1"><a class="page-link">First</a></li>';
                        echo '<li class="page-item halaman" id="'.$link_prev.'"><a class="page-link"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>';
                    }
                    for($i = $start_number; $i <= $end_number; $i++){
                        $link_active = ($page == $i)? ' active' : '';
                        echo '<li class="page-item halaman '.$link_active.'" id="'.$i.'"><a class="page-link">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                    }
                    if($page == $jumlah_page){
                        echo '<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a></li>';
                        echo '<li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link">Last</a></li>';
                    } else {
                    $link_next = ($page < $jumlah_page)? $page + 1 : $jumlah_page;
                        echo '<li class="page-item halaman" id="'.$link_next.'"><a class="page-link"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a></li>';
                        echo '<li class="page-item halaman" id="'.$jumlah_page.'"><a class="page-link">Last</a></li>';
                    }

                    ?>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        <?php
    }
}
```

**Script**

```
import $ from "jquery";

class edu003_ajaxPagination{
    constructor(){
        this.events();
    }

    events(){

        $(document).on('click', '.halaman', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: pluginData.ajax_url,
                type: 'GET',
                data:{
                  'action': 'displayAllUniversity',
                  'page': page
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    response = response.trim();
                    response = response.slice(0, -1);
                    $('.entry-content').empty().html(response);
                }

           })
        });


    }


}

export default edu003_ajaxPagination;
```

Comment: that make error ```Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined``` That because, that data called inside javascript edu003_ajaxPagination class. And the page won't load.

Comment: Try this code. It should work. `$('.entry-content').empty().html(response);`

Comment: I'm already updated the code.. The double table already fixed, but still get "0" below. I'm really confused.

Comment: You didn't share the full code. I cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: actually, that's already full code.. But I'm updated the code.. inserting my the register-cpt.php file

Comment: Sorry. You are using some plugin. cannot use same code in my local.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ACF: Advanced Custom Fields. How about I'm giving the plugins and exported ACF?

Comment: I'm already send you email with the link to drive. Please take a look. Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

at the end of your ajax function before closing add:

```
wp_die();
```

Comment: Hello @Moishy thank you for answering.. wp_die() make my cpt landing page broken. I use wp_reset_postdata(); but still not solve the problem.

Comment: right before the closing `}`